# Strange lines on PDF document converted from Word

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I have a word document that had a watermark in it. I removed the watermark and then saved the document as a PDF. The problem I have is that every page that had a watermark in the Word document now has a line through it - it's like the "border" of the watermark that was removed.

Any ideas on why this is happening and more importantly how to remove it?

Comment: W/o any example will be hard to tell. Please add snapshot.

Comment: See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258 for a method to share the document. All converted documents will be a pain to edit.